# Frage nach dem Verb "widmen"

Tags: accusative, reflexive

*widmen* ist ein reflexives Verb. Nach dem Verb muss der Artikel im Akkusativ sein. Ich habe das Verb in dem folgenden Text gefunden:

> Auch das Technik Museum Speyer feiert mit und **widmet** dem denkwürdigen
>   Ereignis am Donnerstag, 30. Mai 2019 eine Veranstaltung mit Apollo 11
>   Capcom / Apollo 16 Moonwalker Charlie Duke und dem neu ins
>   ESA-Astronautenteam berufenen Matthias Maurer

Ich habe 2 Fragen:

- Warum ist der Artikel nach dem Verb im Dativ?
- Warum fehlt das Reflexivpronomen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Weil [widmen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/widmen) nicht unbedingt reflexiv ist. Ja, es gibt die reflexive Verwendung „*sich* etwas widmen“, aber das ist ein - wenngleich häufiger - Sonderfall von

> [etwas (im Akkusativ) = beschreibt das Objekt]
>   [etwas (im Dativ) = beschreibt den Empfänger]
>   widmen.
>   Die Reihenfolge kann wie meist im Deutschen variiert werden.

In deinem Beispiel *widmet* das Technikmuseum eine *Veranstaltung* (= Akkusativ) einem *Ereignis* (= Dativ). Der Rest ist dann nähere Beschreibung.

Comment: Ist Ereignis dann der Empfänger? Von [link] https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Ereignis hier was bedeuted Ereignis auf Englisch?

Comment: @VictorDoors Gewissermaßen. In English, Ereignis is event, so *in honor of an event (probably mentioned previously in the text, but not in your snippet), the museum holds a <something> with two special guests.

Comment: Maybe confusing: both *Ereignis* and *Veranstaltung* can be translated as “event”.